# find a specific object in a ArrayList

Tags: java

I am making a  small program that should have a class for people(Name, BirthYear) and a class for pets(Name, AnimalType).
In the main I have created a menu so a user can add peoples then the pets.

Now to my question, if I create 4 people "Bruce, Tony, Kevin, William" and the user want to give Kevin a pet, how can i know where in the list Kevin are? Becuse you cant use the `contains()`, can you? well i cant anyways...

The thing is that I have a method in the class for people that creates the pet, because I want them to be linked...

```
public void setAnimal(String dName, String dType)
{
    Animal.add(new Pet(dName, dType));
}
```

This is how my method to create pets work..

```
    private static void createA()
        {
            String P = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"This is the people you can give a pet, please write a name:\n" + People);          
    P = P.toUpperCase();

//I want to write some code here to give a int a number so i cant but it in the get downbelow insted //of "???" 
            boolean b =true;
            while (b != false) 
            {
                try
                {
                ggr3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many pets do you want to add: "));
                b = false;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e + "\nWrite with numbers!");
                }
            }
            while (ggr3 != ggr4) 
            {
                dNamn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write the name: ");
                dTyp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write animal type: ");
                People.get(???).setAnimal(dName, dType);
                ggr4++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Becuse you cant use the contains(), can you?

yes you can only you need to do is to override `equals()` method based on your requirement

Comment: Also, when overriding `equals` you should override `hashCode` as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i strongly agree

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Person> arr = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person kevin = new Person("kevin");
arr.add(kevin);

Person newKevin = arr.get(kevin);

System.out.println(kevin == newKevin); // True b/c they point to the same object.
System.out.println(kevin.equals(newKevin)); // True b/c they have equal values.
```

You need to add a `.equals()` method to your `Person` class.

Answer (score 0):

The way of searching for an object in an array list is with the `indexOf` method.

Example:

```
int x = myAList.indexOf(myObject)
```

It returns the position of `myObject` in the `ArrayList` or -1 if it's not there.